# Excel formula to search three ranges to determine value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Essentially what I'm trying to do is create a formula that will search three different ranges to determine the value of a cell using true/false statements.

`I6` needs to return a value of **"Complete"**, **"Partially complete"**, or **"Not complete"** and it will be searching three ranges `J7:J10 (COMPLETE), J11:J14 (PARTIALLY COMPLETE), J15:J19 (NOT COMPLETE)`.

Each range will have questions `I7, I8, I9` and so on where the options are **YES** or to keep the cell blank.

What I'm trying to achieve is that **IF** `J7:10` are all true **THEN**`I6` will display **COMPLETE** however **IF** any of `J11:J14` are true **THEN** `I6` will display **PARTIALLY COMPLETE** and **IF** any of `J15:19` (can be just one cell) is true **THEN** `I6` will display **NOT COMPLETE**

I've tried using COUNTIF, IF, VLOOKUP, ARRAY but I keep getting the dreaded #NAME

Any ideas?

Comment: `=IF(OR(J15:J19),"NOT COMPLETE",IF(OR(J11:J14),"PARTIALLY COMPLETE",IF(AND(J7:J10),"COMPLETE","DOES NOT FIT THE CRITERIA I GAVE STACKOVERFLOW")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is the question in Columns I will be answered in Column J with either a "Yes" or leaving the cell blank. I highly recommend using Data Validation to limit unintended responses. Assuming my understanding is correct, you can solve this with nested IF statements and COUNTIF/COUNTBLANK statements. Excel will evaluate nested IFs from left to right, so you need to order these in importance of priority (e.g. what if someone has a "Yes" in both the Not Complete and Partially Complete section?). My suggestion would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(J15:J19,"Yes")>0,"NOT COMPLETE",IF(COUNTIF(J11:J14,"Yes")>0,"PARTIALLY COMPLETE",IF(COUNTBLANK(J7:J10)=0,"COMPLETE","THERE IS A DATA PROBLEM")))
```

This assumes that one "Yes" in the Not Complete section overrides anything else, and that the entire "Complete" section must be true to get a Completed result. Note that you'll get the Data Problem error if you have all blanks everywhere.

Comment: Amazing!  COUNTBLANK is what I was missing.  I knew it would be something straightforward.  Thanks for solving my brainfart.